# Adding Default Value to Column Depending on the Value of Another Field in A Model In A Rails 3.2.13 Database Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I already have a date field (string) in my model.  I plan to add other string fields with different long date formats to use in a text search related to the existing date field.  This is to facilitate text searching for the visually impaired.

I have done something like this before which worked just fine.

```
add_column :media_libraries, :media_year, :string, default: Time.now.year
```

However what I want to do is to add the date fields and default the new date field using the value of an existing date field.

I have the code below in one of my views which has the field I want to use to initialize the value of the new long date fields.

```
media_created.to_date
```

Can I do something like this in my migration where I can set a default value depending on the value of another field on the record?

```
add_column :media_libraries, :media_created_en, :string, default: :media_created.to_date.strftime("somedateformat")
```

I have read another post [add a database column with Rails migration and populate it based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284495/add-a-database-column-with-rails-migration-and-populate-it-based-on-another-colu) where one of the answers suggested a query within the migration.  This would be my attempt to implement that.  However others posting on Stack Overflow feel that it is not a good idea to reference other fields in a migration.  For me since this is a one-time thing I'm not worried about those issues.

```
MediaLibrary.update_all(media_created_en: :media_created.to_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"), media_created_fr: :media_created.to_date.strftime("%d %B %Y"), media_created_pt: :media_created.to_date.strftime("%d %B %Y"), media_created_es: :media_created.to_date.strftime("%d de %B de %Y"))
```

I want to do this for existing records since I have over 1000 records to update.  I will either put code in my model or my controller to set the fields for future updates to the model.

I have looked everywhere but can only find built-in functions used for default or the one example above.  The API says nothing other than 'options{}'.  If this cannot be done I am ready to write a method to do this one time in the admin section of my application.

Any help will be appreciated.  I will keep searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept researching and found nothing so I decided to try a few things in the migration.  I was not able to successfully incorporate a field on the model in my default values.  Since I was in a time crunch I decided to just create the fields in the migration then wrote a method in the controller to update the fields on my model.  Now I will wrote the code to update the fields for records being added to make sure the fields are updated properly.

If anyone has a solution for this please post it here but I'm moving on.